# StackOverflowError when overriding Hashtable.contains() java

Tags: java, overriding, stack-overflow

I have to make a class to inherit Hashcode and i need to override the contains method.

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object value) {
    if (!this.containsValue(value))
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void add(Object key, Object value) {
    if (!this.contains(value)) {
        this.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Compiles just fine but when i run it i get the StackOverflowError. I think i get some recursive infinite loop but i can't figure it out. Any help is welcomed!
[printscreen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEKgJ.png)

Comment: Ye,s it's recursion, cause you just call `contains` in `contains`. If you want to call the overriden version, use `super::contains`. But if you just call the base class' version of the method, why override at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `containsValue` inside `contains` but looking at the code in `HashTable` you can see that `containsValue` will call `contains` all over again and this will repeat until you get a stack overflow...

**In HashTable.class**

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    return contains(value);
}
```

You should really be doing this

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object value) {
    if (!super.contains(value))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or simply don't override `contains` because this is already doing what you're reimplementing.

Comment: Thank you, i wrote contains without using containsValue and it worked just fine.